# Cordova platform specific config.xml does not include the correct features after build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

One single new feature in my general `config.xml` file gets not copied to my specific iOS config file. This part is missing in the iOS config after running `cordova build ios`

```
<platform name="ios">
    <feature name="SONativeInterface">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SONativeInterface" />
    </feature>
</platform>
```

Whereas all others are transfered correctly. What is going wrong?

Comment: My shortterm solution is a post-build hook which copies the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `plugins/ios.json`:

```
"config_munge": {
      "files": {
        "config.xml": {
          "parents": {
            "/*": [
              {
                "xml": "<feature name=\"SONativeInterface\">" +
                          "<param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"SONativeInterface\" />" +
                        "</feature>",
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```